# Как отлаживать exec?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, exec

Запускаю пример

```
exec("mspaint");
```

Всё норм работает, открывается Paint, страница грузится, пока я не закрою его, то есть всё разрешено и всё работает как надо.
пишу в "выполнить"

```
node.exe C:\OpenServer\domains\flparser\wp-content\themes\twentyten\bronode\main.js mastertimz "сообщение"
```

всё норм работает, делает именно то, что мне нужно, но если я делаю

```
exec('node.exe C:\OpenServer\domains\flparser\wp-content\themes\twentyten\bronode\main.js mastertimz "сообщение" ');
```

то он просто возвращает нуль, и вообще нечего не происходит и никак не узнать даже в чем проблема, есть какой то способ отладки этого?

Comment: Так, стоп.. А на каком языке выполняется exec - на node.js или [на php](http://ideone.com/FalXWO)?

Comment: @mymedia, возможно, ты поторопился с чисткой тегов...

Answer (score 1):

**Если `exec` делается в коде на node.js**

> ```
> exec('node.exe C:\OpenServer\domains\flparser\wp-content\themes\twentyten\bronode\main.js mastertimz "сообщение" ');
> ```

Ну так путь неверный. `\O`, `\d`, `\f`, `\w`, `\t`, `\b`, `\m`... Надо так:

```
exec('node.exe C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\flparser\\wp-content\\themes\\twentyten\\bronode\\main.js mastertimz "сообщение" ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, поможет второй параметр функции `exec` [док](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Если нет, можно попробовать более сложный запуск через `proc_open` [док](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).